# Ordering the plot of a pivot by count for each week

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When plotting the below data set:

```
date = ['2/18/2019','2/18/2019','2/18/2019','2/18/2019','2/25/2019','2/25/2019','2/25/2019','2/25/2019','3/4/2019','3/4/2019','3/4/2019','3/4/2019',
        '3/11/2019','3/11/2019','3/11/2019','3/11/2019','3/18/2019','3/18/2019','3/18/2019','3/18/2019']
name = ['P','L','E','N','P','L','E','N','P','L','E','N','P','L','E','N','P','L','E','N']
count = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,1,7,1,2,2,7,1,2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'name': name, 'count':count}).sort_values(['date','count'],ascending=[True, False])
```

I would like to maintain the order each week, ie. within every week the values should be ordered by count, for example 3/18 we should have L first, then either P or N and then E.

However, the order breaks after pivoting, and when plotted it shows the data alphabetically. Any way to make it plot by count within each week?

```
piv = df.pivot(index='date', columns='name', values='count')
piv = piv.reset_index(level=piv.index.names)
piv.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0, grid=True)
```

Comment: Can you show an expected output?

Comment: This is a pandas problem. You need to get the dataframe in the order you want, plotting will just happen automatically in that very order.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest BWM below orders pivot by highest value in max date, but is there a way to do sorting within each date?

Comment: Not automatically. Of course you can sort each row by itself, but then you loose the correct labeling (or you would call your columns "Highest", "second highest" etc). I wouldn't recommend such plot anyways, because its hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of columns is how the bars will be stacked. If you have E, L, N, P in your pivot table, that will be the order of the series (current code). You can change this order, but all bars will have the same order. Here is an example ordering the bars by count of Letter group, (i.e. E = 2)

```
piv = df.pivot(index='date', columns='name', values='count')
piv = piv.reset_index(level=piv.index.names)
cols = ["date"] + piv[list("ELPN")].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).keys().tolist()
piv = piv[cols]
piv.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0, grid=True)
```

[image]

[image]

I suspect you want a different order for each bar. I don't believe this is possible with Pandas, but it could probably be done with matplotlib directly.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be plotting correctly- does it not hold for all cases which is why you said you suspect I want a different order for each bar? The order should be my count

Comment: Note that this hard codes the sorting of the column. If the data changes, the column order will still remain as specified in the code: cols = list("ELPN")

Comment: I see. Then making it equal to the values of name should take care of that issue right?

Comment: Please note, the ordering is not hard coded, the ordering is specified by ascending order of letter total, i.e. L has the highest count, E has the lowest. Note the two lines I added to the OP's code: piv = piv[cols] shuffles the order based on the re-ordering of cols in the prior line.

Comment: @user8834780 this will hold for all cases. I thought you might want each bar to have a different order of the segments. e.g. bar one is L,N,P,E whereas bar two is N,P,L,E. That would be trickier... glad this works for you.

Comment: Sorry that is what I need and what I meant by whether it will hold for all cases like if we change N for 3\18 to 1.  In that case we would need 3\11 and 3\18 to have a different order- according to count per name that month. Also FYI LNPE are not the only values, new ones can be added at any point

Comment: Replaced list("ELPN") with list(df["name"].unique())

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the data on axis 1 and then plot.

```
df.pivot(index = 'date', columns='name', values='count')\
.sort_values(by='2019-03-18', ascending=False, axis=1)\
.plot.bar(stacked = True, grid = True)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry the sort is meant to be within each week, ascending based on count for name